# While writing scala test cases not able to compare List of strings or Array of strings

Tags: scala

*I am parsing JSON string which is Result(List(Array(String))). When I write a test case for this it fails as instances are different:*

```
Some([Ljava.lang.String;@486bc9a4) Some([Ljava.lang.String;@4cbf4f53)
parse(jsonString) shouldBe Result(List(Array("success")))
```

case class definition:

```
case class Message(id: Int, status: String)

case class Result(id: Int, message: List[Array[Message]])
```

parsing:

```
    def parseJson(): Result = {
        val json = parse(
         """
          {
             "id":1,
              [
               message:{
                 "id": 10001
                 "status": "success"
               },
               message:{
                 "id": 10001
                 "status": "success"
               }
              ]
            }"""
    (json.camelizeKeys).extract[Result]
   }
```

while testing when I call the above method it returns something like below:

```
Right(Result(1, Message(10001,[Ljava.lang.String;@4cbf4f53)))
```

**when I test above method instead of getting actual string I get object instances which vary every time I execute this code. How to test this code**

Comment: Need more details, hard to understand.

Comment: Java arrays do not properly implement `equals`. Easiest is probably to convert them to a Seq before comparing.

Comment: @thilo I have edited question with sample code. Need to test parse string in one go.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, it's not a good practice to use `Array` in a case class, because it is nothing but a Java array, which means the equals comparison will result in false even if they have the same objects inside. (Another reason is that it's mutable!).

Assuming you're using `ScalaTest`, `shouldBe` would still work for directly comparing the Array objects, because it does a deep comparison:

```
Array("A", "B") shouldBe Array("A", "B") // this is fine
```

However, for case class, `shouldBe` delegates the responsibility of comparison to the case class, which will result in `false` because the arrays almost always point to different objects.

As to your sample code, the JSON is invalid and needs to be corrected as below:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "messages": [
    {"id": 10001,"status": "success"},
    {"id": 10001,"status": "success"}
  ]
}
```

and the case class would be

```
case class Result(id: Int, messages: List[Message])
```

Now, you're free of Arrays, and you can safely do your comparisons like below:

```
parse("...") shouldBe Result(1, List(...))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can convert an array to list: `myArray.toList`

or if you have an option:

`myOpt.map(_.toList)`

but your question is not very clear. let me know if this is not exactly what you are asking (add more details - maybe your test code)

Comment: There is a JSON string which I am parsing using json4s in corresponding case classes. When I write the test for testing the parsing logic it returns corresponding case class with List of Array of String objects rather than actual strings like Ljava.lang.String;@486bc9a4. The hash of the string varies every time I run the test case due to which test fails.

Comment: can you add a code snippet of your test? and your case class definition?